# Issues accessing values in std::array type C++

Tags: c++, stdarray

I am new to C++ and currently trying to write a simple Blackjack game. I am trying to create a Deck function which generates the 52 cards in an array. I am having issues with accessing the values in the std::array from my function. 
I am calling the function "create_deck" in the main function, but I am only getting the first index of my Deck array. I think I am getting mixed up with pointers, but I am not sure how to debug this.

Any suggestions?

```
array<string,52> create_deck()
    {

    array<string,52> Deck;        //array to store the deck  

    array<string,13> Cards = {"A","2","3","4",
                        "5","6","7","8",
                        "9","10","J","Q","K"}; //stores all the different card 

    int count = 0;              //stores the index for Deck array 

    //index each card type 
    for(int card_index = 0; card_index < 13; card_index++)

        {
        //index each suit per card type 
        for(int suit_index = 0; suit_index < 4; suit_index++)
            {
            //append each suit of the specific card type to the deck
            Deck[count] = Cards[card_index];

            //check to see if cards are being added to the deck
            cout << Deck.at(count) << endl;
            }
        }

         return Deck;
     }

int main() {
         array<string,52> myDeck = create_deck();

         for(int index =0; index<myDeck.size();index++)
             {
             cout << myDeck.at(index) <<endl;
             }

         return 0;
     }
```

Comment: You are not incrementing `count`

Comment: You can increment `count` or you just write `suit_index * 13 + card_index`. You don't need `count`. A second problem I see is, you have no way to differ between a `peak A` and a `heart A` in the resulting array.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it! My code works fine now.

Comment: I am currently writing a basic black jack game, the suits will be incorporated later. Thank you!

Comment: Very intresting read on how to debug a small program: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing count++ at the end of the inner loop. You're not sure how to debug this: run it in debug mode and "step by step" checking the different variables could help.